# How to create 300ppi image in php?

Tags: php, flash, image-processing, gdlib

I need to know is there any method available in PHP through which I can create images in 300ppi? I saw the documentation of GD library but can't found any info. Is there any method through with I can process image and set the ppi?

Alternatively is there any method available in flash that convert the image resolution?

Thanks

Mani

Comment: It seems like resizing is your only option in GD. Look into this comment on PHP.net. Imagick for php is probably the way to go: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setresolution.php#95533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a sample code you can use:

```
imagejpeg($image, $file, 75);

// Change DPI
$dpi_x   = 300;
$dpi_y   = 300;

$image   = file_get_contents($file);

// Update DPI information in the JPG header
$image[13] = chr(1);
$image[14] = chr(floor($dpi_x/255));
$image[15] = chr($dpi_x%255);
$image[16] = chr(floor($dpi_y/255));
$image[17] = chr($dpi_y%255);

// Write the new JPG
file_put_contents($file, $msg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it. I'll not forget to accept the answer then it works :)